# Bug configuring Cloud SQL instance? Error encountered while trying tutorial

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm following the tutorial at https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-sql and hit an issue with the section "Configure the new Cloud SQL instance".

Basically, I can't click "Save" successfully when entering the "0.0.0.0/0" network configuration. Chrome's Javascript Console shows an error "Custom HTML/JavaScript blocked. See go/13687728."

What's going on?

I tried continuing with the tutorial but hit an issue at the "npm run-script init-cloudsql" step.

Thanks for the help / fix!

Comment: Hi, I'm from the Cloud SQL team, this is a bug in the UI, you probably have an entry on your network list that is empty, try removing it and then clicking `save`. This is being fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a work around that might get you moving:
Click Add Item, Enter details, then click Save. Do not add another until the done message appears.

Comment: Ok great! Yeah, the UI had led to some confusion, since I previously clicked "Add Item" twice.